# Get data and make it variable from firebase

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get data from current user, like company: "ZeroMax", and then assign this data to global variable.
And use this variable to clarify the path for firebase. I hope you will understand my question by looking into my code. Everything works just fine, except asssigning

> this.comp = user['company'];

This is my drivers.service.ts file:

```js
export class DriversService {

  user: User;
  comp = '';
  constructor(private db: AngularFirestore, private auth: AuthService, private afAuth: AngularFireAuth) { }

 getUsers() {
  return this.auth.user.pipe(
    take(1),
    map(user => {
      //  user['company'];
      this.comp = user['company'];
      return user['company'];
    })
  )
 }

  findUser(value) {

    if (this.comp.length <= 0) {
      return this.getUsers().pipe(map(user => {
      this.comp = user;
      console.log('Bye', this.comp);
      return this.comp;
      }));
    }

    let email = this.db.collection(`companies/${this.comp}/users`, ref => ref.where('email', '==', value)).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(
      take(1)
    );
    let name = this.db.collection(`companies/${this.comp}/users`, ref => ref.where('name', '==', value)).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(
      take(1)
    );
    return [email, name];
  }
}
```

And this is my add-driver.page.ts file:

```js
export class AddDriverPage implements OnInit {
 
  users = [];
  participant = '';
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(private driverService: DriversService, private loadingCtrl: LoadingController, private auth: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }

  addDriver() {
    const obs = this.driverService.findUser(this.participant);

    forkJoin(obs).subscribe(res => {
      if (!res || !res.length) {
        return console.log('Got undefined');
      }
      for (let data of res) {
        if (data.length > 0) {
          this.users.push(data[0]);
          //console.log(res);
        }
        console.log(res);
      }
      console.log('it works:', this.participant)
      this.participant = '';
    }, error => {
   console.log('Here you got an error: ', error);
});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not **where** you access the `this.comp` variable, but **when** you access it. By the time your `this.db.collection(`companies/${this.comp}/users`` now runs, the `this.comp = user` hasn't run yet.

Any code that needs access to the data from the database, needs to be inside the callback that is executed when that data is available.

So for example:

```
if (this.comp.length <= 0) {
  return this.getUsers().pipe(map(user => {
    let email = this.db.collection(`companies/${user}/users`, ref => ref.where('email', '==', value)).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(
      take(1)
    );
    let name = this.db.collection(`companies/${user}/users`, ref => ref.where('name', '==', value)).valueChanges({ idField: 'id' }).pipe(
      take(1)
    );
    return [email, name];
  }));
}
```